# placing two pieces of different data side by side in R

Tags: r, dataframe, bind

I am trying to place two datasets of 3 columns side by side so that they span 6 columns. They have the same column headings.

The first one is:
[image]

The next one is:
[image]

How can I place them side by side across the page so that they total 6 columns? As you can see they are different row lengths.

I want to then be able to download them as a single .csv.

I have tried using `rbind`, full bind, `cbind`, `merge`, etc. but nothing seems to work for this very simple task.

Comment: Use `dput()` to provide your sample data.  It is not possible to illustrate the answer to your question with a picture. Is TRB character data? "Inactive" is not a valid value for numeric data. You should be able to use `cbind()` if you add 4 rows of NAs to the next one.

Comment: couldn't get this to work thats why i put a picture,  the data will have text in it also. Just placing three rows of information next to another three rows of information is so hard it seems. Might just do it in excel instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `merge` on the row names by using 0 for the `by` argument, then remove the rowname column (i.e., `[,-1]`). Then, if you want to have duplicate column names (which is not a good idea), then you can replace the names after merging. Here, I just use subsets of `mtcars` as an example.

```
results <- merge(df1, df2, by = 0, all = TRUE)[,-1]

names(results) <- c(names(df1), names(df2))
```

**Output**

```
   mpg cyl  disp  mpg cyl disp
1 21.0   6 160.0 21.0   6  160
2 21.0   6 160.0 21.0   6  160
3 22.8   4 108.0 22.8   4  108
4 21.4   6 258.0 21.4   6  258
5 18.7   8 360.0   NA  NA   NA
6 18.1   6 225.0   NA  NA   NA
7 14.3   8 360.0   NA  NA   NA
8 24.4   4 146.7   NA  NA   NA
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- mtcars[1:8, 1:3]
row.names(df1) <- NULL

df2 <- mtcars[1:4, 1:3]
row.names(df2) <- NULL
```

To apply to more than 2 dataframes, then you can use `Reduce` over your list of dataframes:

```
results2 <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, by = 0, all = TRUE)[,-1],
       list(df1, df2, df3, df4))

names(results2) <- unlist(lapply(list(df1, df2, df3, df4), names))
```

Comment: This works thanks! If i wanted to merge say 20 different sets of data in this way is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: @Panda_moan_i_am I added another option for if you have more than 2 dataframes. So, this would also work if you had 20 dataframes. You can also do other things to get all those dataframes into a list without typing them out. For example, if they are all in your global environment and start with "df", then we could put those into a list (i.e., `Pattern1_list <- do.call("list", mget(grep("^df", names(.GlobalEnv), value = TRUE)))`). Or you can read in .csv files and put those into a list of dataframes to work with.